# Simple Python SumIf Equivalent

Tags: python, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame that I want to group by and aggregate based on certain conditions and given a simplified example below.

```
|Key|Amount|Bitcoin
|ABC|100|0
|ABC|200|0
|ABC|100|1
```

Desired Output:

```
|Key|Total Amount|Bitcoin Amount
|ABC|400|100
```

Now I could easily groupby the key and sum the amount and seperately create a dataframe with just bitcoin transactions, group that and join the two dataframes but there must be an easy one line of code to handle this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how do you arrive at 100 for Bitcoin Amount?

Comment: 100*1 + 0*100 + 0*200?

Comment: ah okay, thanks ;)

Comment: I wish I had 100 bitcoin. Unfortunately 10 years ago UK banks did everything they could to prevent UK citizens buying them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would approch this as follows

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"Key":["ABC","ABC","ABC"],"Amount":[100,200,100],"Bitcoin":[0,0,1]})
df["BitcoinAmount"] = df["Amount"]*df["Bitcoin"]
print(df.groupby("Key").agg({"Amount":"sum","BitcoinAmount":"sum"}))
```

output

```
     Amount  BitcoinAmount
Key
ABC     400            100
```

Not strictly one-liner, but it is simple to understand. Note that this would work for `df["Bitcoin"]` being not only `0`s and `1`s but also `False`s and `True`s.

Comment: perfect thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can add another column of amount * bitcoin and then just groupby Key and sum:

```
df['Bitcoin Amount'] = df['Amount'] * df['Bitcoin']
df2 = df.groupby('Key', as_index=False).sum()[['Key', 'Amount', 'Bitcoin Amount']]
```

Output:

```
   Key  Amount  Bitcoin Amount
0  ABC     400      100
```

You can add `.rename(columns = {'Amount':'Total Amount'})` at the end of the groupby line if column names must match your output.